# Way to group items in multiselect combobox - Telerik Kendo UI

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

Is there a way to group items in multiselect combobox of Telerik Kendo UI.
I have found templates only to customize the items look and feel.
Can I group the items?

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's quite old, but still missing answer and someone (with poor googling skills) might need an answer.

Grouping is controlled by a `dataSource` property `group`:

```
dataSource: {
    /*other configuration*/
    group:  
    { 
        field: "modelPropertyName" 
    }, 
}
```

where model property, you want to group by, needs too be specified.

[Kendo api and example](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/grouping)